# how to redirect all url in my domain to none-www

Tags: redirect, iis

I used this code for redirect my site to none-www url.but this just affected in main url and don't affected in other url in my domain.
for example: **https://www.yourdomain.com/pro/fa/123** don't redirect to **https://yourdomain.com/pro/fa/123**

```
<rule name="Redirect to non-www" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" negate="false"></match>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://yourdomain.com/{R:1}"></action>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^yourdomain\.com$" negate="true"></add>
      </conditions>
    </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect `https://www.yourdomain.com/pro/fa/123` to `https://yourdomain.com/pro/fa/123`; you need to use the rule below.

```
   <rule name="Redirect to non-www" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.yourdomain\.com$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://yourdomain.com/{R:1}" />
   </rule>
```